# How to write a log in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

My App records food consumption in two places in the database and then discounts the inventory. When reviewing, the two records are being done correctly, but the inventory is not updating to the correct value.  I would like to see a log of whether there was an error or how the inventory is being updated (I suspect that sometimes it is discounted twice), but I do not know how to do that since I cannot see the print in console (App is in Alpha tests with remote users).

Is there any way I can see or register what happens in the database (log)?

I'm using `.push().set` to write the two records in Firebase and I'm using `ServerValue.increment` to update the inventory in this way.

```
  Future<bool> descontarAlimento(String idEmpresa, String idAlimento, double consumo) async {

    try {
      db.child('bodega/alimento/$idAlimento/cantidad')
        .set(ServerValue.increment(-consumo.round()));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    return true;

  }
```

I'm considering to add one line in the write as
`db.child('logs').push().set('Inventory discounted in $consumo')`
and one line following `print(e)` as
`db.child('errors').push().set('Inventory error $e')`, but, I'm not sure if it is a good idea.

What's the best way to view or record a "write operation log" in Firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database does not keep a user-accessible log of operations, as that would become cost prohibitive quickly.

Writing a log from the client is definitely a valid option, as is adding a Cloud Function to do this replication for you.

If you can reasonably reproduce the problem, I'd recommend also running the [database profiler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile) to see if it shows any unexpected operations.